# Вычленить кликабельный элемент по строке JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как можно вычленить кликабельный элемент на странице по строке, например "Hello, world!", используя чистый JavaScript.
То есть алгоритм должен дойти до первого родителя с элементом onclick и совершить клик, как я понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Можешь попробовать обернуть `"Hello World"` в `<span>` с классом. Например:

```
<span class="clicked">Hello World!</span>
```

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.clicked');

elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```